# Manage google accounts centrally for a company

Tags: google-analytics, active-directory, google-tag-manager, google-authentication

Our company is using more and more google tools (Google Tag manager, google anyltics, google 360, google maps...).  Each of these tools allows us to manage users and manage authorisations (we have personal google accounts, "company" google accounts and accounts from users in external partners).  We are reaching a point when managing all these accesses separately becomes unwieldly.  Is there a way to manage all these authentications centrally ?
We are thinking of a tool like Active Directory or its sister AAD where you can centrally disable an account and block the user from accessing all applications.  This is especially handy when users leave the company. (In an even more advanced scenario we would like to grant access to certain users only for a certain amount of time - like until a marketing campaign finishes but we realize most tools don't support this).
So I was wondering whether this is possible out-of-the-box or if needed with a third party application ?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.

Comment: Server Fault is more for system administrators.  My question is IMHO something they will not be able to answer.  I know that it is not a programming question too but this is the largest group which is why I posted it here.  I guess I will have to take it to some of google's forums or helpdesks.  Tx.